# iFrame related tests failing on azure devops

Tags: iframe, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines

I'm running Selenium UI Tests on azure devops build pipeline. the tests have iFrame invocation. They pass locally when running on visual studio but when running in the pipeline, the iframe is not being detected. iFrame not detected and they are failing. can someone please help me?

Comment: Normally, Selenium UI Tests need a UI where a Browser is being launched and the test steps are being executed visually in the Browser. Is this a Selenium Headless Browser Testing? Could you provide some relevant parts of your code & Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

> iFrame related tests failing on azure devops

If you are using hosted agent, there will be many factors that cause this problem, such as network speed, browser version, Selenium Web Drivers version, and some other browser settings, etc.

You could check this agent info from the [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md#microsoft-hosted-agents).

To resolve this issue, we need create a self-hosted agent. You could check this document to create your private agent so that you have an agent closer to your local environment:

[How to Set Up a Private Agent in Visual Studio Team Services](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-tea)

Hope this helps.